Does short CSST line off of copper need to be grounded to main panel?
The LP gas in my house runs through soft copper tubing.  I am adding a gas range and have a chunk of CSST left from adding heat to an outbuilding.  If I tap into the copper and run CSST to the range (about 10ft) does the CSST need a 6 gauge ground wire back to the panel?
I could just go with more copper but was trying to use up the CSST and not buy a roll of copper.  However, if I have to buy a 6 gauge ground, it may end up costing more!  Thanks for any advice.

Is the copper not already grounded?

Not that I can tell.  Is it typical for it to be grounded?

It's a gas line, so, yes. NEC 250.104(B) Other Metal Piping. If installed in or attached to a build‐ ing or structure, a metal piping system(s), including gas piping, that is likely to become energized shall be bonded to any of the following:
Equipment grounding conductor for the circuit that is likely to energize the piping system
Service equipment enclosure
Grounded conductor at the service
Grounding electrode conductor, if of sufficient size
One or more grounding electrodes used
(continues...)

I went under house and did more investigating.  There is soft copper from lp tank coming into house.  It then connects to black pipe that feeds furnace and water heater.  That black pipe is grounded to frame of house (it is a manufactured home with steel beams.  I do not see anything to the panel, just to the frame so I don't know if that is considered grounded?  The soft copper I was going to tap into feeds a fireplace but comes off the copper that comes from the lp tank BEFORE it converts to black pipe.   So I don't know if that is considered grounded either?

So you're going to have every type of gass pipe by the time you are done. If one section of metallic pipe is grounded, they all are, unless there's some sort of non-conductive joint, which would be highly unusual AFAIK.

You have to ground the copper part, not the CSST. CSST cannot be bonded due to the outer sheath.
Your copper gas line should be bonded somewhere to your main electrical ground (usually where the pipe goes into the house, which is often near the main electrical).
As long as your copper is bonded, just connect the CSST to it and you should be good.
